# Finding the time complexity function of these nested for loops

Tags: c++, function, time, time-complexity

Keep in mind that the following pseudo code is similar to c++, so i will use a c++ tag

```
void matrixmult (int n, const number A[][], const number B[][], number C[][])
{
   index i, j, k;

   for(i = 1; i <= n; i++)                //the i for loop will run n + 1 times
       for(j = 1; j <=n; j++)             //the j for loop will run n(n+1) times
           C[i][j] = 0                    //this will run (n-1)n times                                  
           for(k = 1; k <=n; k++)         //the k for loop will run (n-1)(n+1) times
               C[i][j] = C[i][j]+ A[i][k] * B[k][j]; //this will run n((n-1)(n+1))
```

I was instructed by my professor to find the time complexity function of the very last line of code above

I believe that the time complexity function is T(n) = n(n-1)(n+1)

I need someone to double check my work, did i make a mistake somewhere? did i even get the correct time complexity here?

any help will be appreciated

Comment: http://www.cs.upc.edu/~jordicf/Teaching/programming/pdf/MATH02_Complexity.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You have three nested loops, looping n steps each, so it's `n^3`.

Getting more detailed. Depending on the model of computation, you could instead count the number of assignments, comparisons, multiplications and even memory accesses.

Comment: ok thank you, but did i get the correct time complexity for each line of code? can you double check for me please? i would appreciate it

Comment: How did you come up with n-1 and n+1 ?

Comment: i determined that the i for loop runs n +1 times because the loop will obviously run n times, but it will also run one more time after n because it need to check if i <= n is still true...

Comment: Oh. No that's now how it works. You only count the times you enter the loop. That's the case, because we assume that just the the final comparison (when i=n+1) is not taking any time, at least smaller than the time of the j loop.
It depends on the level of detail you are expected to provide.